# jquery select a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have an html page that contains several Bootstrap modals.  I want to close them using jquery.  But, I'm having trouble selecting them.

This is a sample of the html:

```
<div class="modal-footer span5">
  <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save Material">
</div>
```

And this jquery(coffee script) doesn't work:

```
$(".modal-footer .btn").each.click ->
  alert 'commit'
  $(this).modal "hide"
```

Or this:

```
  $(".modal-footer .btn").click.each ->
    alert 'commit'
    $(this).modal "hide"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a javascript code. Try this:

```
$(".modal-footer .btn").click(function(){
  alert('commit');
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Anyway I don't understand why you're closing the modal with jquery if bootstrap does that automatically.

Comment: I'm using a simple_form in Rails and I haven't been able to get Bootstrap to close the modal on commit.  So, I'm trying a different way.

Comment: I have multiple modal-footers on the same html page.  Don't I need to include .each some way?

Comment: no, you're using a class in the selector so all elements with this class will be chosen.

Answer (score 2):

JS engines don't interpret Coffeescript. Instead that block needs to be compiled into javascript first. (or you can just write javascript directly).

If your .modal-footer class comes from the default bootstrap modal, that means its only part of the overall modal html block, the footer might not be the best place to attach the handler to close it.

Out of the box, bootstrap comes with a default modal structure like this:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-    labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
       <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
       <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

To close it, the easiest way would be to use the built-in bootstrap behavior, but by referencing the outermost html element that comprises the modal, in this case the div where id="myModal":

$('#myModal').modal('hide');

For your example, if you know the id of the container:

```
$(".modal-footer .btn").click(function(){
    alert('commit');
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});
```

If not, you could traverse up the tree using a string of .parent() calls, like the example in the previous response.

Unless I am missing something...

Comment: $('#myModal').modal('hide')  - This might not work - I have multiple bootstrap modals on the same page

Comment: EDITED TO CORRECT ERROR: `$(".modal-footer .btn").click(function(){
      alert('commit');
      $(this).parent().parent().modal('hide');
    });`